# ObjectInputStream.readObject does not retrieve object

Tags: java, android, arraylist, objectinputstream

I would not surprised if the reason ObjectInputStream.objectRead does not seem to work for me is because I missed something obvious.

Below, you will find the code, and application log output.

No exceptions are thrown. The code executes to completion.

However, the file retrieved from the SDCard is empty (as evidenced by .size() being 0) although when I check it on the SDCard its size is greater than 0 (several KBytes) and I am able to write to the file (append mode) without problems (as evidenced that after .writeObject operations files size increases.

I am stuck. I probably missed something obvious but I cannot find the problem.

I would really appreciate feedback, suggestions or a resolution to the problem.

Thanks,

Alex Donnini

SOURCE CODE UPDATE ON 100315-2

```
 protected static synchronized void readUserLocationInformation() throws StreamCorruptedException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
 {

 ArrayList<userLocationInformation> mUserLocationInformation = new ArrayList<userLocationInformation>();

 int mUserLocationInformationSize = mUserLocationInformation.size();

 createUserLocationDatabaseOnSdCardStorage();

    userLocationInformation userLocationInformationHolder = new userLocationInformation();
    userLocationInformationHolder.lat = myAndApsLatlng[0];
    userLocationInformationHolder.lon = myAndApsLatlng[1];
    System.arraycopy( myAndApsLatlng, 0, userLocationInformationHolder.myAndApsLatlng, 0, myAndApsLatlng.length);
    userLocationInformationHolder.estimateTime = System.nanoTime();

    mUserLocationInformation.add(userLocationInformationHolder);

    mUserLocationInformationSize = mUserLocationInformation.size();

    try {
        Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformationSize - " + mUserLocationInformationSize);

        if(mUserLocationInformationSize > 0)
        {
            for(int f = 0; f < mUserLocationInformationSize; ++f)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformation.get(f).estimateTime - " + mUserLocationInformation.get(f).estimateTime);
                Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformation.get(f).lat - " + mUserLocationInformation.get(f).lat);
                Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformation.get(f).lon - " + mUserLocationInformation.get(f).lon);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               


    //write object to external storage START $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

    Object objectToBeStoredHolder;

    FileOutputStream objectNameFileOutputStream = null;
    OutputStream objectNameBufferedOutputStream = null;
    ObjectOutputStream objectNameObjectOutputStream = null;

    objectToBeStoredHolder = mUserLocationInformation;

        try
        {
            try
            {

                   Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - object - "+userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject);

            Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - setting up objectNameFileOutputStream --- ");

            objectNameFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(objectStorageLocationDirectory+userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject, true);

        } catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

            try 
                {

                   Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - object - "+userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject);

                    Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - setting up objectNameBufferedOutputStream --- ");

                objectNameBufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(objectNameFileOutputStream);
            } 
                catch (Exception e1) 
                {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        try
        {

               Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - object - "+userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject);

            Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - setting up objectNameObjectOutputStream --- ");

            objectNameObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(objectNameBufferedOutputStream);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

               Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - exception - object - "+userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject);

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try 
        {

               Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - objectNameObjectOutputStream.writeObject - object - "+userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject);

            objectNameObjectOutputStream.writeObject(objectToBeStoredHolder);

        }

      finally
      {

           Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - finally objectNameObjectOutputStream for object - "+userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject);

            objectNameObjectOutputStream.flush();
            objectNameObjectOutputStream.close();
      }

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

               Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - object - "+userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject);

            Log.i(TAG,
                    " - readUserLocationInformation - FAILED to write object ObjectToBeStored --- ");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        //write object to external storage END $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

    Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - retrieving user location database stored on SDcard as arraylist --- ");

    FileInputStream userLocationObjectFileInputStream = null;

    ObjectInputStream userLocationInputStream = null;

    Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - setting up FileInputStream --- ");

    userLocationObjectFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(objectStorageLocationDirectory+userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject);

    Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - setting up ObjectInputStream --- ");

    userLocationInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(userLocationObjectFileInputStream);

    Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - retrieving user location list stored in ArrayList from SDcard --- ");

    mUserLocationInformation = (ArrayList) userLocationInputStream.readObject();            

    mUserLocationInformationSize = mUserLocationInformation.size();

    Log.i(TAG, "readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformationSize - "+mUserLocationInformationSize);

    if(mUserLocationInformationSize > 0)
        {
            for(int f = 0; f < mUserLocationInformationSize; ++f)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformation.get(f).estimateTime - " + mUserLocationInformation.get(f).estimateTime);
                    Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformation.get(f).lat - " + mUserLocationInformation.get(f).lat);
                    Log.i(TAG, " - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformation.get(f).lon - " + mUserLocationInformation.get(f).lon);
                }
        }

 }
```

APPLICATION LOG - UPDATED ON 100315-2

```
10-05 18:11:51.548: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformationSize - 1
10-05 18:11:51.548: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformation.get(f).estimateTime - 6768145557155
10-05 18:11:51.548: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformation.get(f).lat - 42.35552279549794
10-05 18:11:51.548: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformation.get(f).lon - -71.17862967362912
10-05 18:11:51.548: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - object - userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject
10-05 18:11:51.548: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - setting up objectNameFileOutputStream --- 
10-05 18:11:51.549: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - object - userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject
10-05 18:11:51.549: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - setting up objectNameBufferedOutputStream --- 
10-05 18:11:51.549: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - object - userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject
10-05 18:11:51.549: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - setting up objectNameObjectOutputStream --- 
10-05 18:11:51.549: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - objectNameObjectOutputStream.writeObject - object - userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject
10-05 18:11:51.551: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - finally objectNameObjectOutputStream for object - userLocationDatabaseFileNameObject
10-05 18:11:51.552: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - retrieving user location database stored on SDcard as arraylist --- 
10-05 18:11:51.552: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - setting up FileInputStream --- 
10-05 18:11:51.552: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - setting up ObjectInputStream --- 
10-05 18:11:51.552: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206):  - readUserLocationInformation - retrieving user location list stored in ArrayList from SDcard --- 
10-05 18:11:51.553: I/ContinuousLocationTrackingService(10206): readUserLocationInformation - mUserLocationInformationSize - 0
```

SOURCE CODE OF createUserLocationDatabaseOnSdCardStorage()

```
protected static void createUserLocationDatabaseOnSdCardStorage()
{
boolean userLocationdatabaseCreateActionResult = false;

if(!userLocationDatabaseObject.exists())
{
        try {
            userLocationdatabaseCreateActionResult = userLocationDatabaseObject.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "createUserLocationDatabaseOnSdCardStorage - FAILED to create userLocationDatabaseObject --- ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     if (userLocationdatabaseCreateActionResult) {
            Log.i(TAG, "createUserLocationDatabaseOnSdCardStorage - userLocationDatabaseObject created successfully --- ");
     } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "createUserLocationDatabaseOnSdCardStorage - userLocationDatabaseObject not created --- ");
     }
}
 else
 {
     Log.i(TAG, "createUserLocationDatabaseOnSdCardStorage - userLocationDatabaseObject already exists --- ");
 }

}
```

DEFINITION OF userLocationInformation CLASS

```
    public static class userLocationInformation implements Serializable, Comparator<userLocationInformation>
    {
        public long estimateTime = 0l;
        public double lat;
        public double lon;
        public double[] myAndApsLatlng = new double[10];
        public double alternateLatitude = 0.0;
        public double alternateLongitude = 0.0;
        public double locationAltitude = 0.0;
        public long locationTime = 0;
        public float locationSpeed = 0.0f;
        public float locationAccuracy = 0.0f;
        public float locationBearing = 0.0f;

        @Override
        public int compare(userLocationInformation one, userLocationInformation another) {

            long estimateTimeOne = one.estimateTime;
            long estimateTimeAnother = another.estimateTime;

            return (one.estimateTime < another.estimateTime ? -1 :
                   (estimateTimeOne == estimateTimeAnother ? 0 : 1));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior try block should be inside the same try block.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. Any ideas as to why objectRead does not retrieve the file (and no exceptions are thrown)? Thanks

Comment: Obviously, I meant readObject. Sorry

Comment: Not while your code is in the unreadable and invalid state it is presently in. Fix it, re-test, and edit your post if stil necessary.

Comment: After removing all try/catch blocks, the result is still the same, mUserLocationInformation is still empty.

Comment: this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974983/object-read-in-with-objectinputstream-not-retaining-value-after-try-catch-block   was very interesting as it seemed to address the issue I am having. However, in my case removing the try/catch blocks made no difference

Answer (score 0):

> after the `writeObject()` call

**What** `writeObject()` call?

There is no `writeObject()` call in the code you posted.

If this is all the relevant code, all you're doing is creating an empty file. You can't rationally expect to deserialize objects from that.

You need to get rid of the logic that merely calls `createNewFile()`, and substitute logic that:

- calls `new FileOutputStream()`
- calls `new ObjectOutputStream()`
- calls `writeObject()` with the data you are expecting to read back from the file later
- closes the `ObjectOutputStream`.

NB See how much better the code looks with a single try/catch?

Comment: The file is written with another method. It works. As I mentioned in my original post, When I check the SDCard on my device, the file exists and grows, as expected, after every execution of the main application of which readUserLocationInformation() is a method. I checked the file names and they match.

Comment: I added to readUserLocationInformation() the code from the method I use to write to external storage. It made no difference. The try/catch clauses do not make a difference as evidenced by the fact that the method used to write to external storage works as expected.

Comment: (a) The file is written by another method that causes this method not to work. You can't describe that as working. (b) Nowhere have I stated that this problem is caused by poor try-catch structuring. I simply said that it was poor, and impossible to understand your code until it was fixed. You are going to have to post the writing method, *as it is*, not some cut-down version that may hide all the bugs. NB You can't append to files created by object output streams, at least not without special treatment. It's difficult to believe there isn't an exception somewhere.

Comment: Thenk you for your attempt to help me. It's not working mostly due to me. I would like to close this question. Again, thanks for trying.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It turns out that it was caused by writing to external storage an empty ArrayList